# Converting Dictionary to list then from a list back to dictionary but with the same values

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi everyone I would like to know how I can do a conversion of a dictionary to a list and then vice versa, as the dictionary already has a set value . an Example is shown below .

```
#Dictionary
  serviceli["Firewall Service"] = "$1.2k/year"
  serviceli["Security Ops Centre"] = "$4.2k/year"
  serviceli["Hot Site"] = "$8.5k/year"
  serviceli["Data Protection"] = "$10.0k/year"
```

Following up I used this set of code to convert it into a list but only wanting the key E.g Firewall service

```
for ser in serviceli:
    upserli = list(serviceli)
    Newserli.append(upserli[0])
    print(Newserli)
```

therefore the list (Newserli) currently looks like this

```
['Firewall Service']
```

but now I would like the list to be converted back into a dictionary with the same key values as shown above , is there any way I can do that ? Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: And where would the rest of the necessary data to build your dict come from??

Comment: @ThierryLathuille perhaps he wanted some placeholder value such as `None` instead of the original data.

Comment: how exactly you want the list to look like? show us example

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille Sorry could you rephrase the question ? Still pretty new at Python at the moment but I think that's the problem I am facing, if I were to convert the list back into a dictionary, It would only have the keys without any values.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I wanted the placeholder value to be the same as the dictionary provided above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to create a new dict that would be the same as the first one, but keeping only the keys in your list, that would be

```
new_dict = {key: serviceli[key] for key in newserli}
```

So, applied to your sample data, this would give:

```
serviceli = {}
serviceli["Firewall Service"] = "$1.2k/year"
serviceli["Security Ops Centre"] = "$4.2k/year"
serviceli["Hot Site"] = "$8.5k/year"
serviceli["Data Protection"] = "$10.0k/year"

newserli = ["Firewall Service"]

new_dict = {key: serviceli[key] for key in newserli}

print(new_dict)
# {'Firewall Service': '$1.2k/year'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries cannot form without values, perhaps fill with placeholders like `None`:

```
serviceli = {x: None for x in serviceli.keys()}
```

You can get keys of dict with

```
serviceli.keys()
```

Do u want to reform dict:

```
another_dict = {k:v for k,v in serviceli.items()}
```

Or `serviceli[:]`

Have keys and values as tuple pairs? `dict(myPairs)`

Comment: I see, but if I would like the placeholders to have the values as given in the dictionary above. Is that possible ?

Comment: Check edit please

Comment: I see, Thanks for the explanation !  got what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

this is how u can transfer it to list of pairs :

```
mylist = list(dictionary.items()) 
>>>mylist  
[("Firewall Service", "$1.2k/year"),("Security Ops Centre", "$4.2k/year"),... ]
>>>mylist[0][0]
"Firewall Service"
```

this is how u make it a dict again:

```
another_dict = {k:v for k,v in mylist} # or simply dict(mylist)
```

does this answer your question?

Comment: I see , yep Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for ? Her I have converted a dcictionary to a key,value pair list and then back to dictionary

```
dct={"Firewall Service":"$1.2k/year","Security Ops Centre":"$4.2k/year","Hot Site":"$8.5k/year","Data Protection":"$10.0k/year" }
print(dct)
dctlst=[]
for key,value in dct.items():
    dctlst.append([key,value])

print(dctlst)

resdct=dict(dctlst)
print(resdct)
```

Comment: Not quite but I see what the purpose of this , Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it:

```
#Declaration
serviceli={}
dict_to_list = []
list_dictionary = {}
temp = []

serviceli["Firewall Service"] = "$1.2k/year"
serviceli["Security Ops Centre"] = "$4.2k/year"
serviceli["Hot Site"] = "$8.5k/year"
serviceli["Data Protection"] = "$10.0k/year"

#loop through the dictionary items and store in TEMP and then append to final list
for key,value in serviceli.items():
    temp = [key,value]
    dict_to_list.append(temp)

#construct dictionry from new list
list_dictionary = {item[0]  :  item[1] for item in dict_to_list}
print("This is the original Dictionary", serviceli)
print("This is the Dictionary created from List: ", list_dictionary)
```